# Need right student name from 1 million indexed queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed 15 years data that has  1 million indexed queries, which has students information like name, date of birth, address. If I tried to parse the report i.e pdf of the student its show duplicates like multiple student name because of same dob. I have used students last name and dob in must query.

```
query = {"query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match_phrase": {"doc": dob}},
                {"match_phrase": {"doc": last_name.strip()}}
            ],
            "should": should_phrase
        }
    },
```

**Desired ouput**

Appropriate student name details alone should be append in excel/db

Comment: Can you post the query you use and an example of a data object in your index?

Comment: Edited query. I can't add data object , Above scenario I added based on my work environment.